# Updating multiple SQL fields with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Sorry in advance for my amateur knowledge.  I'm creating the basics of a user a database, I have registering working fine fine but I cannot get my update function working correctly.

**Register function**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
```

where $fields and $data are taken from a post filled array:

```
$fields =  '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
$data   =  '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';
```

**Update function**

However using this method for updating records does not work.  I have tried 2 methods:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET ($fields) VALUES ($data) WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
```

and

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET $fields = $data WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
```

The first SQL function does not work (annoying as it does of INSERT) and the second one only updates one value from my array.

Can someone correct me on how this should be done?  For info my array is as follows:

```
$save_data = array(
    'username'      => $_POST['username'],
    'password'      => $_POST['password'],
    'email'         => $_POST['email'], 
    'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'], 
    'bio'           => $_POST['bio']
);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: did you check error message from mysql? try just `echo "UPDATE `users` SET ($fields) VALUES ($data) WHERE `user_id` = $user_id";` before `mysql_query(...` just to check what your trying to query first and debug. I think the problem could be email @ character

Comment: Thanks for the warning and the sources; I will start looking into PDO.  And yes I have yet add my escapes.  Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for UPDATE is to use SET name=value, name=value, ...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

So try this:

```
// Prepare the name-value pairs for the SET clause.
$set = array();
foreach ($register_data as $key => $value) {
    $set[] = "`$key` = '$value'";
}
$set = implode(', ', $set);

// Run the query.
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET $set WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");
```

As a side note, as others have pointed out, mysql_query() is not recommended.
There is http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php, and better yet (apparently), http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. They're a bit more complicated to use, but well worth the small learning curve.

Comment: Thanks for the info; works perfectly like this.  I just need to account for blank fields and it's sorted.  Thanks!